# Is ROM of both P60 & P70 variant of Realme 3 same?

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, stock-rom, oppo-coloros, mediatek

The Realme 3 smartphone, developed by Oppo, comes in two variants: one with the Mediatek P60 chipset and another with the Mediatek P70 chipset. The global variant has the P60 chipset, while the Indian variant has the P70 chipset. The model numbers for these variants are RMX1821 for P60 and RMX1825 for P70.

The question revolves around the compatibility of the ROM (Read-Only Memory) for two different chipsets. According to Realme's official website, the ROM version 'RMX1821EX_11.A.22' seems to be intended exclusively for the RMX1821 device with the P60 chipset. The concern is whether it is feasible to install this ROM on the RMX1825 device, which has the P70 chipset, and whether it will function correctly. Alternatively, it would be helpful to know if there is a separate ROM available specifically designed for the P70 chipset.

Comment: Both are different. Consider the example of Xiaomi devices. Xiaomi devices have two types of OS(rom) one global and other is chinese. Global contains Google apps, and chinese is without Gapps. Likewise, i think realme also have changes in rom.

Comment: @RahulGopi If Gapps are not available or something like that there is no problem . But my main concern is that If I flash the P70 device with P60's ROM; will it brick the device

Comment: both will be different. I am using moto x4 indian version(XT1900-2) which is retail, and in US(XT1900-1) is android one, both rom is different.

Comment: Hi, are you using an AI assistant when rewriting this question? Just curious because some of the wording is peculiar, though it's not really a problem if the original question was written manually, but still be careful with possible [hallucinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucination_(artificial_intelligence)) if not fact-checked manually. Some considerations: [Is attribution required when using LLMs to improve the grammar/formatting of a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385499/241919)

Comment: @AndrewT. yes, and fact checked manually.